# Firebase click_action in Firebase Console, has it changed?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-notifications, firebase-console

I see this has been discussed, but I want to know if it has changed.

I am using Firebase notifications, and I understand if the app is in the background the onMessageReceived() method isn't called. However if you send with the message click_action and have an intent filter to go you the activity I want it should work.

I have read you can now do this from the console, in advanced options with custom data key, value. With the key click_action. However this isn't working for me.

I have this intent filter in the manifest, inside the activity I want to open.

```
<activity android:name=".Activities.SalesActivity">

        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="OPEN_ACTIVITY" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>


    </activity>
```

In the console I add, click_action as key and OPEN_ACTIVITY as value. But when I click on the notification, it still doesn't go to that class.

Am I missing any code anywhere else? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

click_action is not supported in the console. click_action is only available when sending notification messages through the REST API.

Custom data in the console simply adds key/value pairs in the data payload of the message and does not affect how the notification is displayed or handled on the device.